# Probability question of class ten

Tags: probability

The probability to solve a problem is 4÷5 accurately . If 3 problems are given , what is the probability to solve at least 2 problems accurately?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to find $P(x\geq2)=P(x=2)+P(x=3)$

$P(x=3)$ is just the probability of getting all 3 answers correct, and given that these events are independent, is just $4/5*4/5*4/5$.

Now $P(x=2)$ is the probability of getting 2 answers correct and one wrong answer. For example, you could get the first and second question right and the third one wrong, which would give you $4/5*4/5*1/5$. However, this is not what $P(x=2)$ is equal to. Here is a question for you: How many ways can you get only two questions right? This will help you arrive at your answer.